# Mock DataAccess methods that uses Enterprise Library to return IDataReader

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I was given a task to rewrite an Api and corresponding unit tests. I am still quite new to unit testing and so I am struggling to write the test code for a data access class that uses Enterprise Library. Here is the code:

```
namespace TOS_Landside_BL.Classes {
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Data.Common;
  using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
  using Interfaces;

  public class DataAccess : IDataAccess {
    private readonly Database yasDB;

    public DataAccess () {
      DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory ();
      DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory (factory, false);
      yasDB = factory.Create ("AutomationDB");
    }

    // caller is responsible for closing the reader.
    public IDataReader ExecuteReaderForStoredProcedure (string cmdName, List<DbParameter> parameters = null) {
      DbCommand cmd = yasDB.GetStoredProcCommand (cmdName);
      if (parameters != null)
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange (parameters.ToArray ());

      return yasDB.ExecuteReader (cmd);
    }

    public IDataReader ExecuteReaderForSqlStringCommand (string cmdScript, List <DbParameter> parameters = null) {
      DbCommand cmd = yasDB.GetSqlStringCommand (cmdScript);
      if (parameters != null) {
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
      }

      return yasDB.ExecuteReader (cmd);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the interface IDataAccess:

```
namespace TOS_Landside_BL.Interfaces {
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Data.Common;

  public interface IDataAccess {
    IDataReader ExecuteReaderForStoredProcedure (string cmdName, List<DbParameter> parameters = null);
    IDataReader ExecuteReaderForSqlStringCommand (string cmdScript, List <DbParameter> parameters = null);
  }
}
```

And here is a sample on how I would call it:

```
namespace TOS_Landside_BL.Data {
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Data.Common;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Linq;
  using Classes;
  using Enums;
  using Factories;
  using Interfaces;

  public class LandsideTransactionDataProvider {
    private readonly IDataAccess _dataAccess;

    public LandsideTransactionDataProvider (IDataAccess dataAccess = null)  
    {
      _dataAccess = dataAccess ?? new DataAccess ();
    }

    public LandsideTransaction GetLandsideTransaction (string keyword, bool isKioskID = false)
    {
      var strCmd = isKioskID ? "proc_get_landside_transaction_by_kiosk_id" : "[LandSide].[GetLandsideTransactionDetail]";
      var parameters = new List <DbParameter> () {
        new SqlParameter ("@keyword", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 11) {Value = keyword}
      };

      using (var reader = _dataAccess.ExecuteReaderForStoredProcedure (strCmd, parameters)) {
        return reader.Read () ? reader.CreateLandSideTransaction () : null;
      }
    }
  }
```

In the SetUp method of my test class, I tried this:

```
var dataAccess = new Mock<IDataAccess>();
dataAccess.SetUp(d => d.ExecuteReaderFromStoredProcedure(null, null)).Returns(IDataReader);
```

but it won't accept IDataReader or any concrete data reader classes.

Please advise as to what I'm doing wrong, and any suggestion would really be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mock for the `IDataReader` and set it up for the test as well.

```
var reader = new Mock<IDataReader>();
//..Setup the reader as expected for the test.
//Like reader.Read(), etc.

var dataAccess = new Mock<IDataAccess>();
dataAccess
    .Setup(_ => _.ExecuteReaderForStoredProcedure(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<List<DbParameter>>()))
    .Returns(reader.Object);//return mocked reader.
```

Comment: @RodericAgustin any feedback on the solution.

Comment: Hey, Nkosi! Sorry, I was busy with a project.  Yes, the solution actually worked but I had to do a lot of refactoring/decoupling in the old code.  Thanks again!

Comment: @RodericAgustin if this solution solved your issue you should mark it as the answer so that it can be considered resolved.